# Select 4 rows at random with minimum values in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table:

```
addition
question    answer    box
1 + 1        2         0
1 + 2        3         2
1 + 3        4         1
1 + 4        5         2
1 + 5        6         3
1 + 6        7         1
```

I'm trying to select 4 rows with a minimum box value:

```
SELECT *, MIN(box) FROM {table} ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4;
```

However, it returns only one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a cartesian product (`CROSS JOIN`) of two tables: the first table being what you presented above, and the second being the minimum value for column `box`.

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM {table}
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT MIN(box) from {table})
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4;
```

Notice the subquery in the second half of the `CROSS JOIN`.